# Embedding Lua in C++: Accessing C++ created through Lua, back in C++ (or returning results back from Lua to C++)

Tags: c++, lua

The title probably sounds a bit recursive - but this is what I am trying to do:

I have C++ classes Foo and Foobar;
I am using tolua++ to export them to Lua

In Lua:

```
function wanna_be_starting_something()
  foo = Foo:new()
  fb = Foobar:new()

  -- do something
  foo.setResult(42)  -- <- I want to store something back at the C++ end
end
```

In C++

```
int main(int argc, char argv[])
{
    MyResult res;

    LuaEngine * engine = new LuaEngine();
    engine->run('wbs-something.lua');

    // I now want to be able to access the stored result, in variable res
};
```

So my question is this: how do I pass data from a C++ object that is being manipulated by Lua, back into a C++ program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand how to exchange data back and forth, you should learn about the Lua stack that is the structure Lua uses to communicate with the host program. I guess tolua++ takes care of this for the classes/methods you exported.

Here there is a good start: http://www.lua.org/pil/24.html is for Lua 5.0 but there are indications on how to make it work with 5.1 (which I assume is the Lua version you're using).

If you don't want to dig into all the details, you can always resort to create an ad-hoc C++ method that sets values into a global object. Not the cleanest way, IMHO, but could work.

Comment: Due to time constraints, I'll go for the tactical solution (for now) - i.e. storing values in a global object, which can be accessed in C++. Could you please post (or point to) a snippet that shows how I may do this?

Comment: could you clarify what you mean by an ad-hoc C++ method? . My understanding is this: a C++ method/free function that can be called by the exposed object, to dump data into a static variable in the C++ side. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @oompa, yes a global object would do. I was thinking about passing back a pointer to the object whose method invoked the Lua script. It is surely possible to do it with a Lua userdata, probably looking into tolua++ generated code you can figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know tolua++, but both luabind and luabridge support what you need:
* option 1 is just to have the lua code do  `return whatever`  and you'll get the that in C++. This require that you'll have a template based version of run(), which returns a value.
* option 2 is to use the lua engine to define a function and then use the engine's call method with the function name and parameters. There are several implementations of LuaEngine which support such a call:

    `LuaEngine * engine = new LuaEngine();

    engine->run("function a(v) return v . 'a'; end ");

    valua = engine->call("a", argument);`

Comment: While this might work, consider that you will incur the penalty of compiling the Lua code each time you execute that statement. The proper way of doing this is do load (and compile) the Lua code once and execute the compiled code.  Lua execution is very fast but compiling Lua code each time will slow your program unnecessarily.